# how to update from two sources using subversion?

Tags: svn, versioning

In our Production environment we have JBoss running in a clustered mode with 4+ nodes. The base JBoss is present in subversion and then we have some local changes on each nodes.

What should be the strategy where we can have base JBoss at one location, and local changes versioned at another location.

Is it possible to have updates from two subversion sources at the same folder?
or Is there some other strategy used for such versioning use cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution which we used:

All the configuration of local variables has been converted to use system properties. 
The system property names were made designed in following manner

```
${nodename}_${nodenumber}_${propertyname}
```

and every server has variables defined for nodename and nodenumber in .profile file.

The properties file will define all the combinations. For example: we needed separate values of CONNECTION_COUNT so property file has 8 variables(4 for QA and 3 for PROD)

```
PROD_1_MAX_CONNECTION_COUNT=15
PROD_2_MAX_CONNECTION_COUNT=15
PROD_3_MAX_CONNECTION_COUNT=20

QA_1_MAX_CONNECTION_COUNT=12
QA_2_MAX_CONNECTION_COUNT=6
QA_3_MAX_CONNECTION_COUNT=10
QA_4_MAX_CONNECTION_COUNT=16
```

Now on each server(QA or PROD) the variable name is constructed by means of environment variables defined in .profile file and then appropriate property is picked up.

This allows us to get rid of any local changes on any of the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

> What should be the strategy where we can have base JBoss at one location, and local changes versioned at another location.

Branches per node, vanilla JBoss on trunk and merges from trunk to every branch after commit to trunk (if I understood workflow correctly)

> Is it possible to have updates from two subversion sources at the same folder?

No, AFAIK (in pure form, on merge two sources used for producing result). One WC -> One repo URL. You can "switch" WC to new location, but in  this case WC will be updated to the content of new source. `svn co URL1` + `svn co URL2` will not work

Comment: Thanks @Lazy Badger for the response:) but what if the same files have different versions on various nodes. So it seems that The only solution will be keeping versions of JBoss as a whole for every node in subversion separately...

Comment: If diverged *strings* of files not intersect, then you can *merge changes* from  trunk to branches automatically (it's a job of version control tools). In case of conflict itmust be resolved by hand